# How to cross and fade 2 gradients well?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I would like to blend 2 gradients well to create a ground effect in Illustrator. Like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/UfxIwcY.png]

How can I do this?

EDIT: I still have not figured out how to do this, how can I achieve this???

Comment: Could you post some of your attempts? You say you haven't figured it out yet so showing us where you are would help. Also is there a specific part you're talking about? You say 2 gradients but I see a lot more than that, most of which are just regular gradients, nothing special.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not fully sure what you want to achieve and what your problems are. I assume you talk about the v-intersection between the two hills in the foreground. The gradients of the hills should not be a problem.

You can make the two hills blend into each other using an opacity mask on the foremost hill such that the bottom left part is transparent. The mask is another gradient. The picture below illustrates the components of the scene.

[image: opacity mask on foremost hill]